# SpriteKit: A gap between SKSpriteNodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

When the blue square falls down on the red one a gap will remain. But when I make the blue square fall from a lower position there is no gap. Also when I give the blue square a higher mass the gap (on the ground) under the red square disappears and when the mass is too high the red square is gone.
I also made the squares smaller because the amount of pixels didn't equal the pixels of the png file which led to an even bigger gap. And when I set "showsPhysics" to true there is also a gap to see and even bigger when the squares are not scaled down.

[Gap between SKSpriteNodes (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV2q6.png)

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport


class Scene: SKScene {

var square = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "red"), size: SKTexture(imageNamed: "red").size())
var square2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "blue"), size: SKTexture(imageNamed: "blue").size())
var label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.addChild(square)
    self.addChild(square2)
    self.addChild(label)
}

override func didChangeSize(_ oldSize: CGSize) {


    // Add Scene Physics
    self.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: CGRect(x: -1, y: -1, width: self.size.width + 2, height: self.size.height + 2))
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true


    //Add square
    square.texture?.usesMipmaps = true
    square.zPosition = 11
    square.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: square.size)
    square.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    square.physicsBody?.mass = 0.1
    square.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    square.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    square.setScale(0.25)
    square.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.square.size.height)
    square.name = "square"


    //Add square2
    square2.texture?.usesMipmaps = true
    square2.zPosition = 11
    square2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: square2.size)
    square2.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    square2.physicsBody?.mass = 0.1
    square2.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    square2.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    square2.setScale(0.25)
    square2.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.square.size.height * 6)
    square2.name = "square2"

    //Add label
    label.fontSize = 30
    label.text = "w: \(self.frame.size.width) h: \(self.frame.size.height)"
    label.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height - 30)
    label.fontColor = UIColor.black
    label.zPosition = 100

}
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

let scene = Scene()
var viewSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)

override func loadView() {
    self.view = SKView()

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        view.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: -1, y: -1), size: viewSize)
        view.presentScene(scene)
        view.showsPhysics = false
        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true

    }

}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    scene.size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
}
}
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Comment: when you have showPhysics on, there will always be a perceived gap, but no actual gap.

Comment: I'm curious as to the frames of these nodes. Can you tell me what `topNode.frame.minY` is, and what `bottomNode.frame.maxY` is? This may be something with the textures, and not the actual nodes' frame properties.

Comment: can you also upload the textures so we can download them for testing purposes. Thx

Comment: topNode.frame.minY = 100.822998046875
bottomNode.frame.maxY = 100.657000005245 
I just think now the physics aren't 100% and this is probably the answer.. if it is the real answer I am okay with it. 4 pixels (2x2) equals 1 pixel in code.

Comment: override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval)
when I use this function and update the physicsBody every time the position of the Node has changed it fixes everything. But this can't be the answer this is too much code if you have many nodes and it costs more cpu power

Comment: i think it's possible that your pb isn't scaling 100% with your node. (physics there is always 1 glitch or another) try scaling your node BEFORE assigning the pb (you have scale at bottom of your code as is now)

Comment: your frames are on the same pixel. that is less than one pixel difference :p if you can put this on github i can look at it in more detail.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTjM3.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABMLe.png
Here are the resource pictures. You can copy and paste the code in Xcode playground, add the pictures and rename them. I appreciate your help

Comment: https://github.com/simon2204/Playgrounds

Comment: scaling the node before assigning the pb did also not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scene's width and height has to be multiplied by 2. So the scene has to be 4 times bigger than the ViewControllers view. It's also like that in the game template that Apple provides for Spritekit.

```
scene.size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width * 2, height: self.view.frame.size.height * 2)
```

https://github.com/simon2204/Playground

Answer (score 0):

As proof from the `print` commands, there is no actual gap between the sprite nodes, and with second proof from a super-zoomed-in-screenshot:

[image]

The playground you provided does not replicate an issue, which makes me wonder... what is going on with your project?

pg #2:

[image: pg #2:]

Comment: do you have the same values as me? Also the same width and height of the scene? You can see the size displayed on the label.

Comment: But you can see you have a gap on the ground. Try this one https://github.com/simon2204/Playgrounds
There is no gap on the ground anymore but between the cubes.

Comment: @S.Sch it happens on your playground?? I don't see how. the code is fine.

Comment: when you create a physicsBody with a texture, the gap is really big and you can't even fix is with alphaThreshold.